# Implementing http partial requests with actix

Tags: rust, wget, actix-web

I've made a server which provides larger videos via HTTP-Get requests. The following code snipped is used on the server side:

```
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder, HttpRequest};
use std::str::FromStr;


//Some random data
lazy_static::lazy_static! {
    static ref DATA : Vec<u8> = std::fs::read("data/movie1/bigfile.mp4").unwrap();
}

fn get_all_data() -> &'static[u8] {
    &DATA
}

fn get_part_data(start: u64, end: u64) -> &'static[u8] {
    &DATA[start as usize.. end as usize]
}

fn data_len() -> u64 {
    DATA.len() as u64
}

//Extracts the begin and end from the range header string
fn parse_range(s: &str) -> (u64, Option<u64>) {
    assert_eq!(&s[0..6], "bytes=");
    let split = (&s[6..]).split("-").map(|s| s.to_string()).collect::<Vec<String>>();
    assert_eq!(split.len(), 2);
    (u64::from_str(&split[0]).unwrap(), match u64::from_str(&split[1]) {
        Err(_) => None,
        Ok(a) => Some(a)
    })
}

async fn body_request(request: HttpRequest) -> impl Responder {
    println!("Request received: {:#?}", request);
    let range_requested = request.headers().contains_key("Range");

    if range_requested {
        println!("Range requested...");
        let range_str = request.headers().get("Range").unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
        let range = parse_range(range_str);
        let start = range.0;
        let end = match range.1 {
            None => data_len(),
            Some(s) => s
        };

        println!("Original Range: {:#?}, Interpreted range: {} - {}", range_str, start, end);
        let response = HttpResponse::PartialContent()
            .header("Content-Range", format!("{} {}-{}/{}", "bytes", start, end, data_len()))
            .header("Content-Type", "video/mp4")
            .body(get_part_data(start, end));

        println!("Response: {:#?}", response);
        response
    } else {
        println!("Whole document requested");
        HttpResponse::Ok()
            .header("Content-Type", "video/mp4")
            .body(get_all_data())
    }
}

#[actix_rt::test]
async fn part_test() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .route("/", web::get().to(body_request))
    })
        .bind(("0.0.0.0", 8080))?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

This implementation should be able to resume cancelled downloads. However, the part request is not working with the wget utility, I have already read the [Mozilla entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) on how to respond to partial requests, but I cannot figure out why wget is retrying/not working.

I did the following:

- Start the server with `cargo test part_test -- --nocapture`
- Start wget with `wget -c -v localhost:8080` and interrupt it with ctr-c
- Restart wget with the same command (the `-c` option should resume the operation)

I expected the wget to just resume it normally, however it is not satisfied with the server's partial content for some reason. I would like to know why and how I can fix that.

wget output:

```
user@student-net-etx-0499 rusttest % wget -c -v localhost:8080
--2021-12-22 15:25:43--  http://localhost:8080/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 300017432 (286M) [video/mp4]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                           44%[============================>                                    ] 128,02M   157MB/s               
^C
user@student-net-etx-0499 rusttest % wget -c -v localhost:8080
--2021-12-22 15:25:47--  http://localhost:8080/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Retrying.

--2021-12-22 15:25:48--  (try: 2)  http://localhost:8080/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Retrying.

^C
```

Server output:

```
Request received: 
HttpRequest HTTP/1.1 GET:/
  headers:
    "accept": "*/*"
    "accept-encoding": "identity"
    "host": "localhost:8080"
    "user-agent": "Wget/1.21.2"
    "connection": "Keep-Alive"

Whole document requested
Request received: 
HttpRequest HTTP/1.1 GET:/
  headers:
    "accept": "*/*"
    "range": "bytes=158907840-"
    "accept-encoding": "identity"
    "host": "localhost:8080"
    "user-agent": "Wget/1.21.2"
    "connection": "Keep-Alive"

Range requested...
Original Range: "bytes=158907840-", Interpreted range: 158907840 - 300017432
Response: 
Response HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
  headers:
    "content-type": "video/mp4"
    "content-range": "bytes 158907840-300017432/300017432"
  body: Sized(141109592)

Request received: 
HttpRequest HTTP/1.1 GET:/
  headers:
    "accept": "*/*"
    "range": "bytes=158907840-"
    "accept-encoding": "identity"
    "host": "localhost:8080"
    "user-agent": "Wget/1.21.2"
    "connection": "Keep-Alive"

Range requested...
Original Range: "bytes=158907840-", Interpreted range: 158907840 - 300017432
Response: 
Response HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
  headers:
    "content-type": "video/mp4"
    "content-range": "bytes 158907840-300017432/300017432"
  body: Sized(141109592)
```

```
#cargo.toml
[package]
name = "rusttest"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
[dependencies]
actix-web="*"
actix-rt="1.1.1"
futures="*"
serde_json = "*"
serde = { version = "*", features = ["derive"] }
qr2term = "0.2.2"
async-std= { version= "*", features = ["unstable"]}
async_flag="*"
lazy_static="*"
```